# global object empty after implementing local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

**Context:** Working through the Odin Project and finishing a "ToDo List" application. Trying to implement a functionality where the user will store data locally and be able to re-load data when the app is reloaded.

**What I expect:** I added 2 functions: `saveToLocalStorage` and `getFromLocalStorage` and expect any projects that I create to automatically reload when I refresh the page. They are stored in an object called "allProjects".

**What happens instead:** The first time a user creates projects, they populate as normal. However, when the page is reloaded, *I'm not able to add anymore projects*, AND *the old projects don't populate the page*. I know from console.log statements that the data is being loaded, and am parsing/stringifying the JSONS.

**The really weird part:** When I examine the allProjects variable in the chrome debugger (by hovering over the variable), I can see that it contains all the project objects I have been creating. However, watching that same object under "watch" it shows up as empty. And when I call it in `updateProjectSidebar()` as `Projects.allProjects` (because it is coming from a module), I hover over `Projects.allProjects` and it is empty there too. I figure this is probably why my sidebar won't render, since it sees nothing in that object *to* render.

[A link to my whole code if you wish to see the whole thing in context.](https://jsfiddle.net/krmanski/uonkz7dg/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a scope issue. The allProjects var was being returned before getFromLocalStorage() was run.